# How to tell if something is heap or stack allocated?

Tags: rust, heap-memory, stack-memory

I wonder if there's a way to figure out if a variable is stack or heap allocated.

Consider this:

```
struct SomeStruct;

fn main() {
    let some_thing = Box::new(SomeStruct);
    println!("{:p}", some_thing);
    foo(&*some_thing);
}

fn foo (bar: &SomeStruct) {
    println!("{:p}", bar);
}
```

prints

```
0x1
0x1
```

And then

```
struct SomeStruct;

fn main() {
    let some_thing = &SomeStruct;
    println!("{:p}", some_thing);
    foo(some_thing);
}

fn foo (bar: &SomeStruct) {
    println!("{:p}", bar);
}
```

prints

```
0x10694dcc0
0x10694dcc0
```

I can see that the memory address is much shorter for the heap allocated version but I don't know if that's an reliable way to tell the difference. I wonder if there's something like `std::foo::is_heap_allocated()`

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is *"why?"*. What kind of code would work differently with this knowledge?

Comment: I don't need this code for anything different than discovering the language more :)

Comment: The `0x1` is a dummy address that the Rust allocator returns for zero sized objects, it's not on the heap. See [heap.rs#L90](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9ecc9896dedb426e3f4eb3d23dfc60192fe5275f/src/liballoc/heap.rs#L90).

Comment: I had the same question. I'd like to know because it's of interest to me how the thing is working under the hood. For example this trivial example seems to show everything in near contiguous addresses https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4d9e0b2e94fe179edf9baf961316665c&version=stable . I'm now wondering if all references to the heap take up stack space and it's giving me the address of the stack reference to the heap.

Comment: @MrMesees all the addresses are contiguous because you're only taking (and printing) stack addresses: `num` and `dog` are on the stack, `zoo` is an array so it lives on the stack, and while the "storage buffer" of a `Vec` is heap-allocated you're only printing the address of the Vec-structure itself (a triple of a pointer, a length and a capacity) and that's on the stack.

Comment: @MrMesees incidentally, while a `Vec` is a pointer of sorts it doesn't implement `Pointer` *but* a slice is and does, so if you print `&*mutant_zoo` (or `mutant_zoo.as_slice()`) you'll get the address of the vec's heap buffer. `mutant_zoo.as_ptr()` also works as it returns the raw pointer to the vec's buffer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on some POSIX system, you can probably use the [`sbrk()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) system call with an argument of `0` to determine the current location of the program break, which is the current limit of the heap. If the address of a given value is less than this address but greater than the start of the heap then it's on the heap. I don't know how you'd check if it's on the stack though, which isn't necessarily automatically the alternative of not being on the heap, since it can also be statically initialized or uninitialized data, though that would probably be obvious to you upon inspection of the code. You can probably use the `rbp` register on an x86_64 architecture, which should point to the beginning of the current stack frame. That's if you want to check if it's on the current stack frame, or if you want to check if it's anywhere on the stack you can probably use `rsp`.

I think you can get the start of the heap with the [`end()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/end.3.html) system call using the `end` argument. So the lower bound of the heap would be the result of `end(end)` and the upper bound would be `sbrk(0)`.

Comment: Most modern POSIX systems (/ allocators) use `mmap` to get heap space rather than `(s)brk`. `(s)brk` is formally deprecated on macOS (will trigger warnings), and informally so on most every BSD (where they are called "historical curiosities"). I think the correct way to do this would be to get the *stack base* (`pthread_attr_getstackaddr`), the current stack pointer, and check whether your pointer is between the two.