# How to determine when new() in Rust allocates on stack or heap

Tags: memory, rust, stack, heap-memory, allocation

Is there a way (except looking at implementation and docs) to determine when new() in rust allocates on stack or heap?

Ideally I'm looking for a way to determine this when writing source at a glance. For example trait or parameter that can be added restricting whether heap allocation can take place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if something is heap or stack allocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157201/how-to-tell-if-something-is-heap-or-stack-allocated)

Comment: `new` will always return a value that's on the stack, so unless it returns a known heap-involving thing (e.g. `Box`, `Rc`, `Vec`) there's really no way to know if it allocates, at least until Rust starts getting more Allocator-based APIs then something which takes an Allocator at least tells you that it *can* allocate, though something which doesn't isn't saying that it can't allocate).

Comment: @E_net4thecircusstopper, somehow answers. However, I was more thinking a way to determine it based on the code. So when writing SW I can have better understanding of what is going on at a glance.

Comment: @Masklinn seems like either allocator based API's or some restriction parameters would be nice to have in Rust.

Comment: @AdamM "local" allocators are being worked on (there's [an entire WG on the subject](https://github.com/rust-lang/wg-allocators)), however global allocators will always exist, so unless it's a `no_std` codebase with the global allocator unset it will always be possible for the callee to allocate under the covers.

Comment: @AdamM Rust has the [`Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) trait, which is usually more useful than knowing whether something is on heap or stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions named `new()` in Rust are not special in anayway. So no, you cannot easily determine if something returned by such a function owns any heap-allocated data. Even for [`std::default::Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait implementations there is no restriction nor convention which prevents the `default()` method from doing heap allocations, nor is it usually documented.

Comment: thank you. this confirmed my assumptions. seems like some kind of allocation restrictions would be very useful in rust, especially in embedded or performance critical applications.